# DNS: forwarding the specific TLD to a own dedicated DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We have 2 DNS on BIND9 working as 1 Primary and 1 Secondary, serving our customers in network A. network A is peered with network C without any congestion.

There is another ISP, say network B owner;
B and C is peered but very much congested inbetween.

A and B is not directly peered.

So If A>C, no congestion
If A>B, need to go thru upstream or thru C (very congested)

Domain ABC.tld has 2 different IPs for network B and C, and is hosted in both network.

The problem network A have at the moment, is the query from the roots from network A will return network B's IP of ABC.tld instead of network C's, resulting our customer's route to the domain requires longer time or time out.

Question: Is it possible for us to set up a forwarder for that specific .tld? we would like to forward the related tld to the DNS in network C.

```
              *Web Server*
             |            |
             |            |
             |            |
             B============C
             |            |
    Uptream provider ---- A
```

Comment: Your question is virtually impossible to understand.  Please proofread your question for proper grammar, spelling, capitalization, and punctuation.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Edited for easier understanding

Comment: please draw a diagram.  the question still makes no sense.

Comment: it's still pretty unclear - where are the DNS servers - where are the clients - where's the rest of the internet?  I think I can cobble together an answer, but I'm gonna be guessing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *routing* problem, and it's difficult to solve those with DNS hacks.

The "easy" solution for you is for ISPs B and C to fix the congestion on their peering link.

The real solution is for the customer's webserver to be multihomed, running within its own BGP4 *Autonomous System* with *Provider Independent* IP address space.

They can then stop advertising IP addresses "belonging" to ISP B and C in the DNS, and only advertise their own addresses.

Clients connected via ISP A will then always go over the C to A link, and will not traverse the peering link between B and C, unless for some reason the link between C and A goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Try forwarding such queries to either Google Public DNS, or OpenDNS and see whether your problem is solved.

> zone "tld" in {
>     type forward;
>     forwarders {
>       8.8.8.8;
>       8.8.4.4; 
>     }; 
>   };

Comment: this has _zero_ to do with recursive DNS.

Comment: I did this but kind of not working as the DNS mechanism does not allow TLD been forwarded to other server for resolving. PLease correct me if  I am wrong

Comment: @Alnitak: Indeed. The English in this question (I answered before the diagram) did not help me. But then again English is not the mother tongue for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In site A, you can enter this in named.conf (for both primary bind and secondary bind):

```
zone "ABC.tld" in {
    type forward;
    forwarders { my-server-in-site-C ; my-secondary-server-in-site-C; };
};
```

All DNS queries will go directly to C servers.

Alternatively you can enter this:

```
zone "ABC.tld" in {
    file "slave/ABC.tld" ;
    type slave;
    masters { my-server-in-site-C ; my-secondary-server-in-site-C; other-servers; };
    allow-notify { my-server-in-site-C ; my-secondary-server-in-site-C; other-servers; };
    forwarders {}; /* just in case */
};
```

All DNS queries will be cached locally in the file and refreshed from C servers as needed. I would recommend this as it handles better temporary outages of connection between A and C.

In both cases, the "my-server-in-site-C" can be either itself a master or a slave for the domain ABC.tld.

Comment: Thanks. how about if there are several domains in *.tld that need to be redirect in the same way? to be more specific, i.e. .co.uk, .jp, .cn , etc

Comment: I would use many "zone" clauses, don't know if there is any syntax to ease this.

Comment: stop thinking about this as a DNS problem - it isn't.  DNS is a name -> address mapping system, not a _routing_ system.

Comment: True. OP does seems misguided, but he asked a question and got it answered.

Comment: the comment was intended for the OP, not you.